# My Sharepoint formula not working

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

```
=IF([Sett. Start]<=Today,"Visit Due",IF(ISBLANK([Visit Notification No.]),"Visit Not Due","Visit Done"))
```

I am using above formula in SharePoint List but it is working partially. I am not getting result as "Visit Done" if [Visit Notification No.] is not blank and I am getting same "Visit Due" as result value.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please add the required conditions and expected results for your calculated column in your question? when do you want to check the `[Visit Notification No.]` condition and when do you want to check `[Sett. Start]` condition? Also, what is `Today` in your formula? is it another column in your list?

Answer (score 0):

I created a mockup of your scenario and found there was an issue for me using the Today value and would not actually let me create the calculated formula column, so perhaps that could be part of the issue (although I don't see how it could have been working partially.)

Instead using TODAY() seems to allow the formula to work correctly, at least according to what I believe you are after.

Sample output

[image]

Code

```
=IF([Sett. Start]<=TODAY(),"Visit Due",IF(ISBLANK([Visit Notification No.]),"Visit Not Due","Visit Done"))
```

If you are interested in the error obtained trying to use Today:

[image]